# Check Email is already present or not in org using apex

Tags: apex, error

I just want to whether an entered email is already present in org or not.
I used the below code but I am getting the errors like

force-app\main\default\classes\emailcheck.cls  Unreachable statement (13:17)

force-app\main\default\classes\emailcheck.cls  Unreachable statement (19:17)

**Apex Class:**

```
public with sharing class emailcheck {
    public emailcheck() {
    }
        @AuraEnabled
        public static boolean isEmailExist(String username){
            try {
                
                List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
                conList = [Select Id, Name From contact Where email = :username];

                throw new CalloutException();
                
                return !conList.isEmpty();    
            
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    
                return null;
            }
        }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for duplicate check in contact object based on the email ? If yes, check this link :- [link] (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005fJeQAI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory, both `return` statements are unreachable due to the throwed exceptions.
Since no matters what happens you always throw a `CalloutException` every line after that throw is unreachable. The same goes for the return statement in the catch block.
Please note that there is no reason for that try-catch since that query will never throw an exception. Moreover you don't have to create a new instance of a list if on the next line you're going to overwrite it with the result of a soql.

Anyway just a `SELECT COUNT()` (which returns an integer) would be enough and will always count as 1 row against the query rows limit even if it would scan a million records.

```java
public without sharing class emailcheck {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static boolean isEmailExist(String username){
        return [SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact WHERE email = :username LIMIT 1] > 0; 
    }
}
```

Lastly, since you want to check every contact, the class should be `without sharing`.